# How to sort dates with null values using display table tag

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I have a list of dates, some of which might contain null values.Now I want to display it using display table tag and make it sortable and where the date appears as null I wnat to change it to  the string "NA".How can I do it?
Here is my column(I am using struts 2)

```
<display:column property="firstLoginTime" title="First timelogged onto site" sortable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I was killing time on my iphone earlier.

nb. this is just based on looking at the displaytag docs, but have you tried writing a custom comparator?

```
public class CustomDateComparator implements Comparator<Date> {
    public int compare(Date date1, Date date2) {
        if (date1 == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (date2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        return date1.compareTo(date2);
    }
}
```

In your jsp, displaytag lets you specify a comparator like this -

```
<display:column 
   property="firstLoginTime" 
   title="First timelogged onto site"
   sortable="true"
   comparator="your.project.CustomDateComparator"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the links.but if I create a custom decorator for firstLoginTime column and send "NA" for null dates.Then in case of sorting it will return string sorting for the columns and not date sorting. What I want is for this column sorting will be done only for the non null dates .Null dates will apprea as "NA" other dates will remain dates and not string

Comment: I think I may have been leading you up the garden path mentioning table decorators - give it a go with a custom comparator instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add property i.e. `firstLoginTimeHtml` to display formatted date via getter method. Then add `sortProperty` with your original date.
`<display:column sortProperty="firstLoginTime" title="First timelogged onto site" sortable="true">`
`<c:out value="${row.firstLoginTimeHtml}"/>`
`</display:column>`